# How to catch when layers visibility change in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-10.0, development, arcgis-engine

I'm trying to regenerate a Legend in a Pagelayout whenever the layers visibility are changed in the TocControl. What is the best way to catch when a layer visibility is changed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Watch for the VisibilityChanged event on the feature layer that you want to track.

Something like the following (taken from [here](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=993&t=224603)):

```
private ILayerEvents_Event pLayerEvents;

void mActiveViewEvents_ItemAdded(object Item)
{
    if (Item is ILayerEvents_Event)            
    {
        pLayerEvents = Item as ILayerEvents_Event;
        pLayerEvents.VisibilityChanged += new ILayerEvents_VisibilityChangedEventHandler(pLayerEvents_VisibilityChanged);
    }
}

void pLayerEvents_VisibilityChanged(bool currentState)
{
    //do something here
}
```

A little more information is available [here](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/componenthelp/esriCarto/ILayerEvents_VisibilityChangedEventHandler.htm) and [here](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/componenthelp/esriCarto/ILayerEvents_VisibilityChanged.htm).

The links provided above point to ArcGIS 9.x content. If you plan on using ArcGIS 10, [documentation is available here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/ILayerEvents_Interface/00120000072w000000/).

Comment: ArcGIS 10 documentation is over this way: http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/ILayerEvents_Interface/00120000072w000000/

Comment: The sample only workes on the root level layers, so the only way to catch change in visibility is by adding an event listener on every layer?

Comment: @Herb Thanks, updated. @MatthiasWestin As far as I know, that's correct. Since this is a layer-level event, each layer you want to track must be tracked individually. I "solved" this by creating a single method to track all layers, then point to that method when adding the event.

Comment: @Michael-Todd Ok, I make a recursive method looping through the composite and group layers. The Sample code is incorrect the if-statement should check for ILayer or even better ILayerEvents_Event, best regards.